# Возможно ли присвоить на одну кнопку добавление и удаление класса?

Tags: javascript, html, css, анимация, события

Я пытаюсь оформить мобильную версию сайдбара.

Есть в мобильном виде гамбургер с классом `.hamburger_button`
и затемненная область `.mobile`

```css
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
background: rgba(90, 90, 90, 0.9);
width: 88vw;
height: 100vh;
color: white;
```

которая изначально

```css
transform: translateX(100%);
transition: transform 500ms ease-out;
```

но по нажатию на `.hamburger_button` я добавляю новый класс к `.mobile`

```css
.open {
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

в js это выглядит так:

```
var hamburgerButton = document.querySelector('.hamburger__button');
var mobileNav = document.querySelector('.mobile');
function openMobile() {
    mobileNav.classList.add('open');
}
function CloseMobile() {
    mobileNav.classList.remove('open');
}
hamburgerButton.addEventListener('click', openMobile);
mobileNav.addEventListener('click', CloseMobile);
```

Есть решение с добавлением нового блока,***но цель заключается в том,чтобы по нажатию на гамбургер область выезжала и уезжала обратно.***

А пока что она уезжает при любом нажатие на область `.mobile`, и почему это происходит мне понятно.

Comment: так используй `toggle` вместо `add` в `openMobile`: `element.classList.toggle("open");`

Comment: Сделайте самоответ, чтобы Дух вновь не опубликовал ваш вопрос на главной странице через полгода.

Answer (score 1):

**Решено**

```
var hamburgerButton = document.querySelector('.hamburger__button');
var mobileNav = document.querySelector('.mobile');
function openMobile() {
    mobileNav.classList.toggle('open');
}

hamburgerButton.addEventListener('click', openMobile);
```

Спасибо @exvayn